# Best way to optimise For Loops and Do Until Loops

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop, do-loops

I have the following code that searches through folder directories in a DataGridView table, and puts all files of the wanted format into a list, it also gathers a list of their last modified date for later use in the application.

The code works, but it is sore on the eyes. I want to tidy up the following loops to improve efficiency - what I mean is that I have a For loop within a For loop that creates the list of filenames, then I have two separate Do Until loops that search through the list from start to finish to pick out file names that need adjustment.

I would be very interested to learn a better way of achieving the same result, as my knowledge of efficiency in coding is quite elementary. Basically, can this be done in one or two loops, as the idea of looping through the Lists twice seems inefficient?

```
Public Class
    Private Sub btnDirectory_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDirectory.Click

    Dim FileNames As New List(Of String)
    Dim FileDates As New List(Of Date)

    Dim DocNo As String
    Dim rowCheck As String
    Dim ProjectNo As String = "1111"
    Dim FileNameCheck As String
    Dim str As String

    Dim k As Integer = 0 
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Dim CorrectType As Boolean = False

    'The first loop grabs all files of the wanted format from a datagridview table containing all directories to be checked

    For Each rw In Background.Table1.Rows

        rowCheck = Background.Table1(0, k).Value
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(rowCheck) Then

        For Each file As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(Background.Table1(0, k).Value)
            CorrectType = False
            FileNameCheck = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
            If FileNameCheck.Contains(ProjectNo) AndAlso FileNameCheck.Contains("-") AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(FileNameCheck) AndAlso FileNameCheck.Contains(" ") Then
                DocNo = FileNameCheck.Substring(0, FileNameCheck.IndexOf(" "))
                If FileNameCheck.Substring(0, FileNameCheck.IndexOf("-")) = ProjectNo AndAlso CountLetters(DocNo) = 3 Then
                    CorrectType = True                                   
                End If
            End If
            If CorrectType = True Then
                FileNames.Add(FileNameCheck)
                FileDates.Add(IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file))
            End If

        Next
        End If

        k += 1

    Next

    'The next loop tidies up the file formats that contain a "-00-" in their names

     j = FileNames.Count
     i = 0
     Do
         str = FileNames(i)
         If str.Contains("-00-") Then                           
             FileNames(i) = RemoveChar(str, "-00-") ' RemoveChar is a function that replaces "-00-" with a "-"
         End If
         i += 1
     Loop Until i = j

     i = 0
     j = FileNames.Count


     'Finally, this loop checks that no two files have the exact same name, and gets rid of one of them if that is the case

     Do

         Dim st1 As String = FileNames(j - 1)
         Dim st2 As String = FileNames(j - 2)

         If st1 = st2 Then          
             FileNames.RemoveAt(j - 1)
             FileDates.RemoveAt(j - 1)
         End If
         j -=  1
     Loop Until j = 1


     End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: a) Why do you think the 'speed' can be improved? This is I/O bound.

Comment: b) Whenever you see a ForEach loop that needs to do k += 1 you should have used a For loop.

Comment: c) that CorrectType  variable only serves to add an extra IF/EndIf that you can do without

Comment: But you should really have posted this in the CodeReview site.

Comment: Thank you Henk Holterman, I will post this question there now

Comment: Just more an helpfull tip, but have a look into [Dictionaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) , if you have a large amount of data trying to itterate through lists in vb is very slow. Dictionaries (especially if you have unique values such as a filename) are super fast!

Comment: @Chicken I'm not sure where you got that information from, but it's wrong.  Iterating through lists in VB.NET is no different than C# when it comes to performance. Additionally, `Dictionary` won't preserve the order of items.  That's just bad advice all around.

Comment: @bradley from experience my information is correct. I'm sorry you disagree with me but to say I'm wrong is very unjustified. If you would care to share your findings or proof then please do. A dictionary of filenames with unique values doesn't have any bearing on whether it is ordered in this instance. Additionally i didn't compare .net with C# in my comment!?!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is certainly hard on the eyes.

the `For Each rw` loop does not use `rw`. You could replace this with a loop such as:

```
For k = 1 to Background.Table1.Rows.Count
    ' Do things here
Next k
```

You assign `rowCheck` and use it once, but you missed the opportunity to reuse it in the `For Each file` line.

Where you have `CorrectType = True` you can easily place the corresponding code instead.

```
        If FileNameCheck.Substring(0, FileNameCheck.IndexOf("-")) = ProjectNo AndAlso CountLetters(DocNo) = 3 Then
            CorrectType = True                                   
        End If
    End If
    If CorrectType = True Then
        FileNames.Add(FileNameCheck)
        FileDates.Add(IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file))
    End If
```

becomes:

```
        If FileNameCheck.Substring(0, FileNameCheck.IndexOf("-")) = ProjectNo AndAlso CountLetters(DocNo) = 3 Then
            FileNames.Add(FileNameCheck)
            FileDates.Add(IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file))
        End If
```

I must admit, the next two loops made my eyes bleed (figuratively, not literally).

```
 j = FileNames.Count
 i = 0
 Do
     str = FileNames(i)
     If str.Contains("-00-") Then                           
         FileNames(i) = RemoveChar(str, "-00-") ' RemoveChar is a function that replaces "-00-" with a "-"
     End If
     i += 1
 Loop Until i = j
```

becomes

```
 for i = 1 to FileNames.Count
     str = FileNames(i)
     If str.Contains("-00-") Then                           
         FileNames(i) = RemoveChar(str, "-00-") ' RemoveChar is a function that replaces "-00-" with a "-"
     End If
 Next I
```

And

```
    i = 0
    j = FileNames.Count
 'Finally, this loop checks that no two files have the exact same name, and gets rid of one of them if that is the case

 Do

     Dim st1 As String = FileNames(j - 1)
     Dim st2 As String = FileNames(j - 2)

     If st1 = st2 Then          
         FileNames.RemoveAt(j - 1)
         FileDates.RemoveAt(j - 1)
     End If
     j -=  1
 Loop Until j = 1
```

becomes

```
 'Finally, this loop checks that no two files have the exact same name, and gets rid of one of them if that is the case

 For j = FileNames.Count - 1 to 1 Step -1 ' Check my counting here - stop at 1, 2 or 0?

     Dim st1 As String = FileNames(j)
     Dim st2 As String = FileNames(j - 1)

     If st1 = st2 Then          
         FileNames.RemoveAt(j)
         FileDates.RemoveAt(j)
     End If
 Next j
```

Comment: Thank you, I enjoy your attitude - the help is very much appreciated. I'm glad your eyes only bled figuratively. I had to adjust the first loop to 'For k = 1 To Background.Table1.Rows.Count - 1' and the second loop to  'For i = 0 To FileNames.Count - 1', let me know if that should not have been the case

Comment: Jay, that adjustment is fine - good debugging, looks like you are using 0-based arrays.